# DB2/SQL: How to increment the max value when inserting data into table

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables (tables: visit and basket) and I need a way to insert data into table basket with some data from table shopping.

table: visit

| vis_ID | vis_name | vis_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | 2021-12-09 |
| 2 | Lu | 2021-09-02 |
| 3 | Luke | 2021-03-04 |
| 4 | James | 2021-01-19 |

bas_ID is the same ID as vis_ID. I want to insert into basket for all visits >= '2021-05-01' the item 'freebie' with the same visit date 'vis_date' to field basket date 'bas_date'

My problem is, if there were items in basket, the next basket position 'bas_pos' should be the max value + 1. But if there was no basket item in table basket, the bas_pos should 1.

output of
table: basket

| bas_ID | bas_item | bas_date | bas_pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cap | 2021-12-09 | 1 |
| 1 | ball | 2021-12-09 | 2 |
| 1 | fruit | 2021-12-09 | 3 |
| 1 | freebie | 2021-12-09 | 4 |
| 2 | freebie | 2021-09-02 | 1 |

I think I have to implement with subselect? Is my code right for DB2?
Thank you.

```
Insert into basket
  select vis_ID, 'freebie', vis_date, case when(select max(bas_pos) from basket b
                                       where b.bas_ID = c.vis_ID) is null then '1' else int(select vis_ID, 'freebie', vis_date, case when(select max(bas_pos) from basket b
                                       where b.bas_ID = c.vis_ID) +1 end
  from visit c
  where vis_date >= '2021-05-01'
```

Comment: The subqeury will just return c.vis_ID. And then you add 1. Not as intended, I suppose.

Comment: Hi jarlh, I've changed my subselect, do you see any problems with the result, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Insert into basket (bas_ID, bas_item, bas_date, pas_pos)
select 
  c.vis_ID, 'freebie', c.vis_date
, coalesce (b.bas_pos, 0) + rn_
from
(
  select 
    vis_ID, vis_date
  , row_number () over (partition by vis_id) as rn_
  from visit
  where vis_date >= '2021-05-01'
) c
left join 
(
  select bas_ID, max (pas_pos) as bas_pos
  from basket 
  group by bas_ID
) b on b.bas_ID = c.vis_ID
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Could you shortly explain how the "coalesce (b.bas_pos, 0) + rn_" works, only for my/our better understanding, thank you? How can I prevent in code, that a new 'freebie' data set can added a second time into table basket to same bas_ID, when running the code a second time?

Comment: The idea is to enumerate all the inserted rows inside each `vis_id` starting from 1 (with row_number) first. The assumption was, that you could have a number of them for some `vis_id`. Secondly, we join these enumerated rows with a set containing `max (pas_pos)` for each `bas_ID` - to get a "base" value to increment from.

Comment: To prevent the same rows be inserted after next invocation of this query, you may probably use a `not exists` predicate in the 1-st sub-select, if you know the `visit` table Primary Key / Unique Constraint columns, which may be used with this predicate.